# How to append vectors to a list group by group

Tags: r

I want to add some vectors to a list, and I want to that show like this:

```
1.1
2.1 2
3.1 2 10
4.1 10
5.2
6.2 10
7.10
```

this is my code:

```
subsets <- function(s) {
    res <- list()
    n <- length(s)
    s <- sort(s)
    help <- function(temp, index, res) {
        tmp <- temp
        
        res <- append(res, tmp)
        i <- index
        
        while (i < n + 1 ) {
            temp <- append(temp, s[i])
            res <- help(temp, i + 1, res)
            temp <- temp[-length(temp)]
            i <- i + 1
        }
        return(res)
    }
    res <- help(c(), 1, res)
    return(res)
}


s <- c(1, 10, 2)
subsets(s)
```

the output is:

```
1.1
2.1
3.2
4.1
5.2
6.10
7.1
8.10
9.2
10.2
11.10
12.10
```

Could somebody do me a favor? I am a new man for R, and I don't know what should I do...

Comment: Hi! What is your input dataset and expected output, and the logic behind it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My input data is : `c(1, 10, 2)`, I need to find all Subsequences of the vector.

Comment: As I understand, "." is not decimals. 1st number is just a row number.

Comment: You can at the 7th line, `print(tmp)`, that is what i want.

Comment: Yeah~ You're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `combn()`. Loop over number of elements `0:3` sublist should contain (or `1:3` if empty element not wanted). Except the order this is equivalent to Python `[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 10], [1, 10], [2], [2, 10], [10]]`.

```
lapply(0:3, \(m) combn(c(1, 2, 10), m, simplify=FALSE)) |>
  unlist(recursive=FALSE) 
# [[1]]
# numeric(0)
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 10
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[6]]
# [1]  1 10
# 
# [[7]]
# [1]  2 10
# 
# [[8]]
# [1]  1  2 10
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

Comment: This is what I want, that's so kind of u~ I think that in R, it's important not to stick to algorithms, but to return to the mathematics itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your vectors to be in a list, you can use `unlist`:

```r
unlist(list)
# [1]  1  1  2  1  2 10  1 10  2  2 10 10
```

Or add `as.list` if you want everything in a list of one item:

```r
as.list(unlist(list))

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 2

[[4]]
[1] 1

[[5]]
[1] 2

[[6]]
[1] 10

[[7]]
[1] 1

[[8]]
[1] 10

[[9]]
[1] 2

[[10]]
[1] 2

[[11]]
[1] 10

[[12]]
[1] 10
```

Comment: Sorry I guess I still don't get it, but in python I can get something like this: `[[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 10], [1, 10], [2], [2, 10], [10]]`, you can at the 7th line `print(tmp)` look what I want in R.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand, what is your expected output here?